# Proving the Secant Angles in the Circle

Tags: geometry, circles, angle

Ok, I know this is a very easy circle geometry problem, but I want to know that how to prove the theorem of angles in the circle.
Like this image here:

[image]

How can I prove that the angle $X$ is the half of the sum of both angles' measurement of the Arc $AC$ and Arc $BD$? 
This image here:

[image]

How can I prove that the angles $A$ is the half of the difference of both angle measurements of Arc $BC$ and Arc $DE$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the second case.

Draw $\overline{BE}$ and let the measures
of arcs $CB$ and $ED$ be $\alpha$ 
and $\beta$.

By the inscribed angle theorem, the
measure of an angle inscribed in a 
circle is half the measure of its
intercepted arc.

Therefore 
$\angle{E} = \frac{\alpha}{2}$

and $\angle{EBD} = \frac{\beta}{2}$

By the exterior angle theorem

$m \angle{A} + m \angle{E}
= m \angle{EBD}$

Substituting

$m \angle{E} = \frac{\beta}{2} 
- \frac{\alpha}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

For example, in the first case look at the triangle $\;\Delta BCK\;,\;\;K\;$ the point of intersection of both secants. Observe that

$$\angle x=180^\circ-\angle DCB-\angle ABC$$

But

$$\angle DCB=\frac12\angle BMC=\frac12\widehat{BC}\;,\;\;\angle ABC=\frac12\angle AMC=\widehat{AC}$$