# Midpoints of arcs in cyclic quadrilateral

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Do you have any hint? I don't want a solution, please. Only some hints.

Let $A,B,C,D$ the four vertex of a cyclic quadrilateral, and $E,H,F,G$ the midpoints of arcs $AB$, $BC$, $CD$ and $DA$. Show that $EF\perp GH$

[image]

Comment: Hint: [Proving the Secant Angles in the Circle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1766022/proving-the-secant-angles-in-the-circle).

Comment: Simply search for "far arc near arc"

Answer (score 1):

Since the angle subtended by an arc at the circle is proportional to the arc, for arcs $\overset{ \huge\frown}{ABC} = 2\overset{ \huge\frown}{EBH}$,

$$\angle ADC = 2\angle EFH$$

And for arcs $\overset{ \huge\frown}{ADC} = 2\overset{ \huge\frown}{GDF}$,

$$\angle ABC = 2\angle GHF$$

Consider the cyclic quadrilateral $ABCD$, its opposite angles add to $180^\circ$,

$$\begin{align*}
\angle ADC + \angle ABC &= 180^\circ\\
\angle EFH + \angle GHF &= 90^\circ
\end{align*}$$

So $\triangle FIH$ is a right-angled triangle, where $I$ is the intersection of $EF$ and $GH$.